# How can I write text in the border of a JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, border

I am working on a GUI in Java and I have the following code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    public MainWindow () {
        setUpWindow();

        JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();

        upperPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
        lowerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));




        getContentPane().add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void setUpWindow () {
        setSize(600, 450);
        setTitle("Subjects");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4,4,4,4,Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If I compile this, the output I get is:
[image]

As you can see, I have one JPanel at NORHT and another one at SOUTH.

I want to add text in the border of a JPanel so I can get as an output something similar as this:

[image]

I have tried multiple things but I don't know how. Is there a JPanel method that does this? Should I create a JLabel and place it there somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [BorderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html). It can be applied like so:

```
upperPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Favorite subjects"));
```

For a detailed explanation of JPanels, Borders and what's possible (with examples), see the Oracle article [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).